# gtkmm 3 windows 64 bit

Tags: c++, windows, gtk, gtkmm

I don't suppose anyone has managed to build gtkmm 3 for windows 64 bit, or knows of a good build?

There are around 3-4 links on google where people have tried that, but for various reasons I can't get any of them working. Either the pkg-config files are missing (so I can't compile any programs), or I get `incompatible .dll.a` style error messages, or the programs just crash.

I have tried building it myself and failed as I don't think I'm experienced enough, and I tried asking on the gtkmm mailing list and nobody replied. There are official win64 installers but only for gtkmm 2.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://gtkmm-installation.blogspot.com/

Comment: Anyway, as it is now, your question is way too broad for SO, I think...

Comment: You can also build latest gtkmm3 and it's dependencies with latest Visual Studio https://github.com/codekiddy2/Visual-Studio-gtkmm/wiki

Comment: I would have to say that this question is NOT too broad. It's one that an employee of mine has been fighting with. Very simple: how to build gtkmm3 for Windows.

Comment: @JasonMc92 I agree the question is on topic. I have detailed how to compile gtkmm3 for windows here: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2014-September/msg00021.html . I've used 32 bit MinGW so it does not help the OP who wants a 64 bit build. But it may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize the original question is 4 years old.  **gtkmm** on Windows can now be easily installed with [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg).